# Create Group column based on number of times Group appears

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the Company Names [Frog, Chicken, Goose]

I want to create a column called Group Number based the number of times the group appears. See test_df for an example.

Before I used to do a group by based on the zip code, and Company name. However sometimes I would get incorrect counts, and example of the formula used below.

```
df['Group'] = (df.groupby(['ZIP Code','New Home Factor']).cumcount()==0).astype(int)

test_data=({'Company Name':['Frog','Chicken','Goose','Frog','Chicken','Goose'],'Group':[1,1,1,2,2,2]})

test_df=pd.DataFrame(test_data)
```

Comment: what is your expected result when you group Company Name on your test_df?

Comment: The column in test_df called Group...

Comment: I mean, after you code and run the codes, how does your output looks like?

Comment: test_df['Group'] is the desired output. Not sure if I am answering your question?

Comment: `test_df['Group'] = test_df['Company Name'].eq('Frog').cumsum()`?

Comment: That is correct Quang Hoang, thank you.